# Error reading a path in Windows 10 for copying a database from postgres to a csv

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to take a table from a postgres database and copy the contents of that csv into a table. The error I am getting is `psycopg2.error.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "C"` I have looked at the other people who have had the same error but the problem is I already tried what everyone is suggesting and I am printing out my path to make sure it is correct and I have copied and pasted that graph into the file manager and it opens the csv so I am confused as to the issue.

```
path1 = r'C:\Users\Hank\Documents'
tb = 'test29'
path = os.path.join(path1,"Testing.csv")
print(f"This is the output path fro the csv {path}")
def csv_to_postgres():
    sql = f"""COPY {tb} FROM {path} DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"""
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    print(f"Printing to {path} was successful.")
csv_to_postgres()
```

I have also tried string as `"sql query {}".format(path)` and `"sql query %s" path` and none of the three are working. The path that is printed out has been put into the Windows 10 search function and opens the CSV.

Thanks to a comment I was also shown that I could just use `os.path.exists(path)` to see if the path exists and it returns `True` so I am lost.

To further add on to this I was able to make the command work in PgAdmin by changing the file permissions for Everyone but the same exact code still isn't running in Python.

Comment: For future reference, if you're unsure about paths in your code, rather than printing and pasting it into windows search, add an os.path.exists(path) check.

Comment: Didn't know that existed, thank you! Unfortunately that is also returning `True` so I'm still just as lost because it's telling me it exists and doesn't exist at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is the solution to my problem. Basically the issue was that I first had to open the CSV with python and then use `copy_expert` to get it copied in. `tb` is the table name and I believe you need `STDIN` in the sql query.

```
sql = f"""COPY {tb} FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"""
with open(path) as f:
    cur.copy_expert(sql,f)
conn.commit()
```